Looker Studio SQL query with parameters
I wish to find the correct query from Looker zu Azure SQL.
I have been reading this article but it did not work: Link
If I use this query it will work:
SELECT * FROM angebote WHERE Datum >= '2014-01-06' AND Datum <= '2014-01-10' 
The parameters (Von_parameter and Bis_parameter) I have set are  formatted as text, example: 06.01.2014
This query won't work:
SELECT * FROM angebote WHERE Datum >= CONVERT(DATE, @Von_parameter, 104) AND Datum <= CONVERT(DATE, @Bis_parameter, 104);
What do I have to do?
